# Problemas con librería IOUtils en proyecto Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas tardes espero y me puedan ayudar, lo que ocurre es que en un proyecto de android studio necesito utilizar la clase **IOUtils**.

Pero no puedo importar la librería me marca error, ya intente varias cosas descargue el .jar y lo agrege a la carpeta libs y di en add as library también lo agregue al gradle, también intente con file, project structure y agregar dependencia pero simplemente no encuentro una forma en que la reconozca espero y alguien me pueda orientar gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como comentarios adicionales eh intentado con clean project y rebuild y tampoco ah ayudado en nada

Comment: los comentarios adicionales van en tu pregunta, de hecho puedes agregar como trataste de registrarla, etc, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para que reconozca la clase, es importante asegurar tengas la dependencia registrada en tu archivo `build.gradle`, agrégala, esta es la última [versión](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io):

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
```

al definir la dependencia, realiza la sincronización de tu proyecto con los archivos `.gradle`.

Es importante mencionar también que las [librerías Apache están marcadas como obsoletas](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html?hl=es-419#behavior-apache-http-client), por lo tanto debes pensar en un reemplazo.

Para continuar utilizandolas debes activar el "modo legacy" en tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
    ...
}
```